# JQGrid - Drop down value not set correctly when edittype = 'select'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid 4.4.4. I have a column of edittype = 'select'. The value displayed in the row of the grid is correct. But when I edit the row, the drop-down/combo-box value is set to the wrong value. Instead of setting it to the value, it sets it to the label having same text value. The value-label pairs in the drop down is - `{'1':'0','21':'1'}`. The problem is only when the label is same as the value for another item in the options.

Here is the JS fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/ksrini/ehj0nyLu/4/ 
And here is a screen shot that shows the problem.
[image]

The issue is reproducible in 4.6. The JQGrid forum seems to be closed and I can't raise a bug if this is indeed a bug.

Any suggestions on how I can fix it or work around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo which you use don't reproduce the problem because both jqGrid 4.6 and the old version 4.4.4 don't supports *local* data editing. It's important that you use

```js
formatter:'select'
```

Only in the case jqGrid should save *values* of the drop-down/combo-box. In any way you can verify that [free jqGrid 4.9.1](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) don't have the described problem (I used just URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)): http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ehj0nyLu/5/. I can imagine that some bugs exist in the old version 4.4.4, but it's clear that nobody will fix the bugs. So I would recommend you to update to free jqGrid. It's the fork of jqGrid which I continue to develop after Tony have changed the licence agreement for jqGrid in 4.7.1 version. His fork have the name [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). If you will find some bugs in free jqGrid then you can post [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) to GitHub or post the description of the problem on stackoverflow. The *latest* version can be easy fixed, but not the retro version 4.4.4.

**UPDATED:** The bug is fixed in the latest version of free jqGrid on GitHub: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ehj0nyLu/6/. The fixed code will be included in free jqGrid 4.9.2 which I will publish today.

Just for information I repeat what I wrote before in comment: [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L426) of code jqGrid 4.4.4, which you use, like all later versions of jqGrid and free jqGrid (less then 4.9.2) tests for **either the value or the text** during selection of option of `<select>` during editing. It's correct to test for the value only and the select the option by text *only if no option were found by value*. [The fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/0102a6f4bf1d2992e455a97faec652d59db37537) implements the changes.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I still see the issue. Even in your fiddle. When you edit the row for name=Adam, what is the value set in the company drop down? I see 1. It should be 0 as in the grid. Please see screenshot in question.

Comment: @ksrini: Sorry, but you use `editoptions:{value:{'1':'0','21':'1'}}` and the input data contains `name: "Adam", company: '1'` and `name: "Eve", company: '21'`. Thus the company of `Adam` should be shown as `'0'` ('1':'0') and the company of `Eve` as `'1'` ('21':'1'). It do the `formatter:'select'`.

Comment: @ksrini: OK! Now I see at the end the issue. I will examine it more and to post additional information.

Comment: yes it should be shown as `'0' (value=1)` when input data is `name: "Adam", company: '1'`. But it is showing `'1' (value=21)`. And that is the issue. Even in your fiddle which has `formatter:'select'`. My apologies, but I don't fully understand what you are trying to say. Can you please use `editoptions:{value:{'1':'ZERO','21':'ONE'}},`, you will understand the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your second comment. I've added a new answer to the question with a work around for the issue.

Comment: I have to do some other things. Now I'm back. I wrote in my previous comment, that I understood the problem already. It's a bug. I debugged the code and found the place of code which is origin of the problem. During creating `<select>` for edit dialog jqGrid try to find the value `"1"` either as value (from `"1"` and `"21"`) which is correct **or as text** (from `"0"` and `"1"`). So it selects first correctly `'0'` item, but later select `'21'` item because it have the same text. The problem: there are old programs which uses `edittype:'select'` in a wrong way **without** `formatter:'select'`.

Comment: @ksrini: Such programs will not work after one make the fix for the bug. So I will fix the bug in the following way. I will *first* try to find the correct *value* in one loop and will try to find the value as text *in the second loop* **only if the first loop didn't find any option to select**. It should fix the bug and still hold some kind on compatibility for the old wrong code. I will post my answer after I'll make the fix in my fork of jqGrid: in free jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the cause of the bug now.

Comment: @ksrini: I still need to do another things, but you can modify the code of `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` of your copy of old jqGrid in [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L426). If you would remove the part with `|| $.trim(oSv[key]) == $.trim(vl)` jqGrid will work correctly. As I explained before the code of jqGrid will hold still have the part, but in *separate* loop and only if the first loop didn't find the value by `$.trim(key) === $.trim(vl)` compare. I will do the changes in the code of free jqGrid later today or at the weekend.

Comment: thank you. I'lI make the change locally. I truly appreciate you putting in the time and effort to help.

Comment: @ksrini: See **UPDATED** part of my answer and the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ehj0nyLu/6/ which uses the latest sources of free jqGrid

Answer (score 0):

From Oleg's comments in his answer, it seems to be a bug in the code attempting to keep it backward compatible with programs using an older version of JQGrid.

For now I've worked around this issue by getting the value from the selected row in the grid and setting the value of the select input field in the form in `beforeShowForm` function.

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    ...
    $("#<field-id-in-grid>", form).val(<value-from-selected-row>);
    ...
}
```

**NOTE:** I've accepted this (my own) answer for the work around. The fix is mentioned in one of Oleg's comments to his answer. If that can be made as an answer, I'd prefer to make that as the accepted answer.